# Sharepoint 365 Application does not have administrative permissions in tenant

Tags: rest, sharepoint, permissions

I have an application created in my tenant that has the following app permissions granted and trusted.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Yet when I try and use the REST API to do a KQL search (Keyword Query Language) I get the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Application does not have administrative permissions in tenant</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Using the following query in Postman

`https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&amp;refinementfilters='fileExtension:equals("docx")'`

So my questions are :

Why are administrative permissions needed to do a search?
How can I create an application permission that is 'Full Control' + 'Also Search'?

Madness.

Answer (score 0):

To make the app have administrative permissions in tenant, you need to change permission scope to tenant:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```